# Google sheet sends an email when a new form is submitted if a question has a particular answer

Tags: google-apps-script

I hope you can help, I have tried to find a solution but I am unable to find one that resolves my issue.
I have a form that collects information if a student request a change to their course, we are a multi school site and depending on the site, a different member of staff is required to approve the change.
Part of the information collect is the site code OAAd for example, and this information is held in column F.
If a submission is received the 'On form submit' trigger, triggers the script. Currently it doesn't seem to work, yet it triggers without error. If I change the trigger 'On edit' and edit a cell in column F it works fine.
eventually I will use ifElse to add in the additional options for each site, but if I could get it to work for one site that would be great.

```
function sendEmailapproval(e) {
if(e.range.getColumn()==6 && e.value=='OAAd'){
 var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email Addresses").getRange("B3");
 var recipent = emailRange.getValue();
 var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email1.html");
 var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
 var subject = "New Change Log Request Post 16";
 var body = "";
 var options = { htmlBody: htmlText}
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipent, subject, body, options)
 }
}
```

Comment: Pardon my french but it seems rather stupid to switch from an onFormSubmit to an onEdit() trigger.  How do you plan to get the data from the form.

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

There are 2 options to add an `onFormSubmit` trigger:

1. Using the form settings / script.
2. Using the attached spreadsheet script.

Both methods gives an `event` object to communicate with new submmited responese, but threre are differaces between those objet so you need to dicide in advance which method to choose.
You can read more about this topic [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

For your propose, would preder to use the spreadsheet script, since it easier to extract specific values from it.

#### Solution

First, Here is your correct `sendEmailapproval` function:

```
function sendEmailapproval(e) {
  const namedValues = e.namedValues
  const question = 'Question 3'; // copy-paste from the form
  switch (namedValues[question][0])
  {
    case 'OAAd':
      const emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email Addresses").getRange("B3");
      const recipent = emailRange.getValue();
      const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email1.html");
      const htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
      const subject = "New Change Log Request Post 16";
      const body = "";
      const options = { htmlBody: htmlText}
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipent, subject, body, options)
      break;
    // case 'SOMETHING_ELSE':
    // break;
    default:
  }
}
```

Note that `e.namedValues` is an object, where each key mapped to an **array**.
So `namedValues[question][0]` refers to the string value of `namedValues[question]`.

Second, add a trigger to the spreadsheet that attached to the form.

```
function createTrigger() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID").getSheetByName("THE_SHEET_NAME");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmailapproval")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```