# Google sheet onSubmit event does not contain the form reponses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get responses from a google sheet from, I have setup the onSubmit trigger successfully and that actually invokes the desired function but for some odd reason the event does not contain the form response.

I tried to setup the form trigger using both the UI editor and by running this function.

```
function setupTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('addMedicalRecordsOnSubmit')
    .forForm('1agiEov6gDjoTEgUTI2oO9tJWjt1DkyZZmTzMRO8MhIQ')
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

Here is my code onsubmit code which is actually being triggered when I submit the form.

```
function addMedicalRecordsOnSubmit(e) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Console output response is empty:

```
Aug 25, 2021, 8:55:56 PM    Debug   {"authMode":"FULL","response":{},"source":{},"triggerUid":"6856708"}
```

Comment: `function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  e.response.getItemResponses().forEach(r=>{
    console.log('Id: %s\nType: %s\nTitle: %s\nResponse: %s\n',r.getItem().getId(),r.getItem().getType(),r.getItem().getTitle(),r.getResponse());
  });
 
}`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ScriptApp.newTrigger().forForm().onFormSubmit()` the response return in a `formResponse` object (class). Therefor, the log cannot show the accual values.

However, you can manipulate formResponse object to see it's contect.
For example:

```
function addMedicalRecordsOnSubmit(e) {
  console.log(e.response) // expected result: {}
  console.log(e.response.getEditResponseUrl()) // expected result: 'https://...'
}
```

See also my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68924717/google-sheet-sends-an-email-when-a-new-form-is-submitted-if-a-question-has-a-par) about the difference between `onFormSubmit` for spreadsheet and form.